# Why can't I upgrade Linux Mint 15 from Cinnamon 1.8.8 to Cinnamon 2.0, and how do I fix it?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade, desktop, cinnamon

So Cinnamon 2.0 is out, and I've followed the steps people have given for upgrading.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This however doesn't work.  It says I'm already on the newest version.  I've tried doing this from a different DE, but that also didn't work.  I don't appear to have any held packages in apt, so that's not the problem.

Do I need to uninstall Cinnamon and reinstall it? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

`Package: *

Pin: release o=LP-PPA-gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable

Pin-Priority: 800`

to the file in etc/apt/ called preferences (Increase 800 to whatever is higher than everything else)

I also had to install muffin and nemo (from that PPA) to get it to run...

However - I'm having other problems now with muffin not launching.

Answer (score 2):

If the version you want is actually in the repositories, you can install a specific version with this command:

```
apt-get install cinnamon=2.0.2-20131011040008-raring
```

Comment: It shows three versions.  [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/ZabXbziK)  I also tried install and upgrade commands.

Comment: @gryftir OK, and what does `sudo apt-get install cinnamon` do?

Comment: it says I have the newest version available. cinnamon --version gives me 1.8.8

Comment: @gryftir see updated answer.

Comment: I already got Jacob's answer to work for me, before you updated.  I've upvoted you but I haven't accepted your answer.  If another person uses your solution and it works, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

GNU/Linux can has many `DE` simultaneously, such as `KDE`, `Gnome-Shell`, `awesome`,  and so on. You don't need to remove `cinnamon`.Please check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` , i think your problem is conflict of repositories. check it.

If you get a message such as:
`The following packages have been kept back:`
It's not related to your machine, it can has some reason , server , your repositories, and conflicts and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat as the question poster. I am running Linux Mint 15 (Olivia) KDE Edition and have added the repo and done

```
sudo apt-get update
```

quite a few times since last 3 days. However, all i see is cinnamon package at version 1.8.8 in Synaptic or by using command:

```
sudo aptitude show cinnamon
```

I tried to install specific version by giving following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon=2.0.2
```

Nada. I get the error message :

```
E: Version '2.0' for 'cinnamon' was not found
```

Any ideas??

BTW, currently, I don't have cinnamon installed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to install Cinnamon 2 on my Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon and XFCE editions was to remove the base linux mint repository.

Comment: alright... can I do that and then restore it, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm sorry, looks like I spoke too soon.  I am having problems with installing the new Cinnamon in this way.  My Nvidia drivers aren't supported, and so am stuck running Cinamon in software rendering mode.  So I'm going to suggest people don't do this!**

It was Jacob's suggestion that made this work.  A full step-by-step.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then opened the preferences file in etc/apt/ like Jacob said.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

and pasted in the information he advised

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable
Pin-Priority: 800
```

and saved the file.

Finally I ran the last line of code:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

*And Cinnamon has been upgraded - yay!  Jacob's suggestion works.  Thanks to both of you - gryftir and Jacob.  =)*

Comment: **These are the files that are automatically installed:**
  cinnamon-bluetooth cinnamon-desktop-data cinnamon-session
  cinnamon-settings-daemon cinnamon-translations cjs
  gir1.2-cinnamondesktop-3.0 libcinnamon-desktop0 libcjs0c
  libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-video2.4 python-opencv

Comment: **The following packages were upgraded:**
  cinnamon cinnamon-common cinnamon-control-center
  cinnamon-control-center-data cinnamon-screensaver gir1.2-muffin-3.0
  libcinnamon-control-center1 libmuffin0 libnemo-extension1 mdm muffin-common
  nemo nemo-data nemo-dropbox nemo-fileroller nemo-share